# reload page after ajax using swal

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I have some swal code like this:

> ```
>   $('#config-reset').click(function(event) {
>     event.preventDefault()
>     swal({
>       text: 'some text',
>       dangerMode: true,
>       showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
>       buttons: true,
>     })
>     .then((result) => {
>       if (result !== null) {
>         return $.post("url")
>       }
>       return false
>     })
>     .then((result) => { 
>       if (result.result.success == 'done') {
>         swal({ text: "Done", icon: "success", }); 
>       }
>       else{
>         swal(result.result.error); 
>       }
>     })
>     .catch(err => { 
>       swal(err.statusText); 
>     });
>   })
> })
> ```

After the ajax call returns and Done/success swal is cleared I want to reload the page. If I put the reload after the swal it happens before the swal is cleared. Same if I put it in a .then after the second .then. How can I get the reload to not run until after the alert is cleared?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` function of javascript.

Comment: How would I use that for getting the reload to run after the dialog is dismissed?

Answer (score 1):

Please add option `onClose`.

```
swal({
    text: "Done",
    icon: "success",
    onClose: function(){
        location.reload()
    }
});
```

If you use sweetalert v1, please try like this:

```
swal({
    text: "Done",
    icon: "success"
    confirmButtonText: "Ok",
},
function(isConfirm){
    if(isConfirm)location.reload()
});
```

Or:

```
swal({
    text: "Done",
    icon: "success"
}).then((value)=>{
    if(value)location.reload()
});
```

Comment: I don't want to dismiss the dialog after a time period - it gets dismissed when the user clicks OK - that is when I want to do the reload.

Comment: No - it seems the onClose function is not called.

Comment: Is onClose only supported in sweetalert2? I am using sweetalert1.

Comment: I don't understand why you didn't try with `then` callback. Because you used it when you call first `swal`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233531/discussion-between-gretchen-richards-and-larry-martell).

Comment: Thanks. I got this to work using the last example you gave.